# Skipping the sql execute of a specific variable in case it is null in php

Tags: php, sql

I have a function which receives 3 variables.

```
function configurationSet(int $id, string $name, string $last=null) {
    $s = pdo()->prepare("update myTable set nameCol = ?, lastCol = ? where id = ?");
    $s->execute([$name, $last, $id]);
}
```

**I don't want to use an 'if' statements in this function or to create a new function**.

Is there a way that in case `$last==null` (the function wasn't called with the `$last` variable so it is set to null by default), the execution will not update `$last` with a `null`?

To make it clear, there are already values in `firstCol` and `lastCol`, I want to prevent an overwriteof `lastCol` in case it is `null` (just update the `firstCol`).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You could add a condition the the value you set using [ifnull()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Comment: with ifnull() , what do i set as 'expr2'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution i managed to get working

```
function configurationSet(int $id, string $name, string $last=null) {
   $s = pdo()->prepare("update myTable set nameCol = ?, lastCol = CASE WHEN ? is null THEN lastCol ELSE ? END where id = ?");
   $s->execute([$name, $last, $last, $id]);
}
```

"CASE WHEN ? is null THEN script ELSE ? END"